# Запрос на подсчет с условием

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, ms-access

Сделал запрос в `PostgreSQL`

`SELECT Count(public."Postanovlenie"."Warning")
FROM public."Postanovlenie"
WHERE public."Postanovlenie"."Warning"::integer=1;`

Как сделать то же самое в `MS Access` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет о конструкторе запросов, то можно так:

```
SELECT Count([Warning])
FROM [Postanovlenie]
WHERE [Warning]=1
```

Или

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM [Postanovlenie]
WHERE [Warning]=1
```

В VBA можно так: `DCount("*","Postanovlenie", "[Warning]=1")`